# How to extract values from Tika OCR using Tesseract

Tags: java, apache-tika

Hello I am trying to extract the text content from the image using Tesseract with Tika

```
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

        TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
        config.setTesseractPath("/usr/local/bin/");
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
        parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);



        try {
            parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }

        System.out.println(handler.toString());
```

I am always receiving an empty value? I am not sure how to get the content from the parser can any one help me?

Comment: What happens if you try calling the Tesseract Parser directly, rather than going via AutoDetectParser?

Comment: I receive the same empty value. But when i use Tesseract in terminal it works fine.

Comment: Did you try following any of the [Troubleshooting Tika steps](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika)?

Comment: Hi Ramesh? Did you make it  work?? can you share the solution? tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare `config.setTesseractPath("/usr/local/bin/")` if you got `tesseract` in your system path,  check it first for example with:

```
public static boolean checkIfExecutableInPath(String exec) {
    String path = System.getenv("PATH");
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(path)) {
        for (String dir : path.split(":")) {
            if (new File(dir, exec).exists()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And add to your code:

```
if (!checkIfExecutableInPath("tesseract")) {
    config.setTesseractPath(pathToTesseractDir);
}
```